# two sided t-test in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, t-test

If I have a df like this:

```
        normalized_0  normalized_1  normalized_0   mean      std
Site                           
0           NaN      0.798262      1.456576       0.888687  0.118194
1      0.705540      0.885226           NaN       0.761488  0.047023
2      0.669539      1.002526      1.212976       0.826657  0.077940
3      0.829826      0.968180      0.988679       0.871290  0.032367
```

How do I calculate a two sided t-test for 0, 1, 2 vs. 3?

I tried it with:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

df['ttest'] = ttest_ind(df, d.loc[3])
```

But this does not work... The error I get is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

How would you solve this?

Comment: what's the error? do you have the same problem if you do `df.loc[3]` vs `df.loc['3']`?

Comment: @Yuca thanks for the tip, I added the error

Comment: what about my second question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer might be completely off, as I've only read about t-tests :)

What I understood from your question is that you have a table with both normalized values and their descriptive statistics (mean, std).

Each index value within this table is a `category` of your analysis, and you want to compare categories `[0, 1, 2]` vs `[3]`.

I also assume you only need normalized values as input arrays, without mean or std.

---

```py
selected_data = df.copy()
selected_data = selected_data[['normalized_0', 'normalized_1', 'normalized_0.1']]
selected_data['ttest'] = [ttest_ind(a=selected_data.iloc[3, :].values, \
                                    b=selected_data.iloc[x, :].values, \
                                    nan_policy='omit') for x in np.arange(len(selected_data))]

df.join(selected_data['ttest'])
```

```py
        normalized_0  normalized_1  normalized_0.1 mean      std       ttest 
Site                           
0           NaN      0.798262      1.456576       0.888687  0.118194  (-0.7826642930343911, 0.4909212050511221)
1      0.705540      0.885226           NaN       0.761488  0.047023  (1.4370158341444121, 0.24625840339538163)  
2      0.669539      1.002526      1.212976       0.826657  0.077940  (-0.19764518466194855, 0.8529602343240825)
3      0.829826      0.968180      0.988679       0.871290  0.032367  (0.0, 1.0)
```

---

`a` and `b` parameters are row values of selected columns

```
# values of third category for example
selected_data.iloc[3, :].values 
# array([0.829826, 0.96818 , 0.988679])
```

`omit` is to ignore nan values when calculating test (by default the parameter of `nan_policy` is set to `propagate` which returns nan if any missing values are present).

Comment: Sounds good, but here I get ```KeyError: "None of [Index(['normalized_0', 'normalized_1', 'normalized_0.1'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"``` as an error

Comment: because you have two columns named as `normalized_0`, I renamed the second one to `normalized_0.1`. So my columns were: `Index(['normalized_0', 'normalized_1', 'normalized_0.1', 'mean', 'std'], dtype='object')`

Comment: youre right... But how do I rename one column? Because I alvays get this Key error, if I try to change the name...

Comment: @lefrcom you could try this: `df.columns = ['normalized_0', 'normalized_1', 'normalized_0.1', 'mean', 'std']`

Comment: Now I get this ```TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.float64") to str```

Comment: @lefrcom at which line did this error occur? that's strange :(

Comment: @lefrcom you might as well try `range` instead of `np.arange`, that would be the same. though I'm not sure what's raising an error

Comment: Got my mistake... pandas has read the 'nan' as a string instead of a numpy.float value... Now your solution works! Thank you so much!!